# English-Hindi Dictionary

Tags: dictionary

Do we know if any English to Hindi language dictionary is available for Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there's a lot of Hindi dicts for stardict: [google query](https://encrypted.google.com/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=stardict+hindi&btnG=&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1)

Comment: stardict.org says that "Install Dictionaries in Linux:
                                                               To install these tarball dictionaries, do this:
tar -xjvf a.tar.bz2
mv a /usr/share/stardict/dic"                                                                                                                     I have found stardict-shabdanjali-2.4.2.tar.bz2 from one of the file sharing website.  Can somebody please guide me how to go ahead with the installation?

Comment: I have dicts in `~/.stardict/dic` -- as I remeber  it is enough just to put them there -- the dir is added recursively.

Comment: How can we reach to ~/.stardict/dic?  I am unable to locate this folder in file system.  Sorry, if I expose my total ignorance here.

Comment: I use krusader file manager. In there `Ctrl-.` toggles show/hide "hidden" config/settings file/dirs.

Answer (score 0):

Download the free English-Hindi Dictionary for 32-bit Linux platforms:[DonateWord](http://www.donateword.com/download.php)
The Dictionary has been tested on Ubuntu,Mint,Suse and Fedora(32-bit).